# Google Cloud Datastore get entities by list of keys

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a set of entities which I want to retrieve from GCD. Some (or most) entities, however, I already have loaded in memory. So my approach was first to find out which keys existed. So I did a ancestor query with a projection for `__key__`

I figured all I had to do was filter out which keys I still needed to load and do something equivalent to `ndb.get_multi` I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation. Perhaps I missed it?

I will potentially have hundreds of relatively large entities for the same ancestor query. Only retrieving the right entities would make the difference between getting only a handful or all of them.

TLDR:
I am looking for an equivalent of `ndb.get_multi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Lookup` method supports fetching multiple keys:

```
req = datastore.LookupRequest()
req.key.extend([key1, key2])
resp = datastore.lookup(req)
```

Comment: Aaah yup, I missed it. Thanks